# How to perform revocation check with iText7?

Tags: itext7

Why my [Pdf](https://apps.primteksolusindo.com/example-prepared-signed.pdf) certificate status "Revocation checks status were not perform"?

[image]

How to perform revocation check with iText7?

Do I need to do this before injecting .p7s into the Pdf?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please read the message at the bottom of the dialog:

> The selected certificate has errors: Not time valid

Most likely your certificate simply is beyond its validity, check it on the *Summary* or *Details* tab.

(The pdf you linked is incomplete.)

Comment: Adding LTV information only helps if the certificate still was valid when you applied the signature.

Comment: btw, where should I put addLtv? .. when Pdf preparation or when injecting the Pdf?

Comment: If I addLtv after I inject and certificatelevel is 1 then then certificate would be invalid, how to keep valid certificate and addLtv.. thanks